# How to identify if it was a tap or click in iteminvoked event for listview

Tags: html, css, windows-8

I am working on a metro style app using html5 and javascript languages. Please find my question as below :

I have below iteminvoked event of a listview  in which I am trying to run css3 transition. I do not want to run the animation when user clicked by mouse as I already have css3 declarative animation (:hover) for mouse hovers scenarios. My problem is how do I identify if it was a tap or mouse click.

```
     itemInvoked: function (args) {
        if (appView.value === appViewState.snapped) {
            // If the page is snapped, the user invoked a group.
            var group = Data.groups.getAt(args.detail.itemIndex);
            nav.navigate("/pages/groupDetail/groupDetail.html", { groupKey: group.key });
        } else {

            var winitem = args.srcElement.querySelector(".win-item");
            var actionicon = winitem.querySelector(".item-image");
            var actiontitle = winitem.querySelector(".item-title");
            var showTransition = WinJS.UI.executeTransition(
              args.srcElement,
              [{
                  property: "border-color",
                  delay: 0,
                  duration: 500,
                  timing: "linear",
                  to: "#333"
              },
              {
                  property: "z-index",
                  delay: 0,
                  duration: 500,
                  timing: "linear",
                  to: "999"
              },
              {
                  property: "transform",
                  delay: 0,
                  duration: 500,
                  timing: "linear",
                  to: "scale(1.1)"
              }
              ]
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, on shouldn't differentiate between mouse and touch, except where it's explicitly different.

It should also be noted that the :hover state on an element is still there for touch, but it is only on hold - when you hold your finger on an element, you will see the hover effect.

You should look at customizing the default animations that the list view plays non invoke; although maybe that's not possible. (I'm talking about the default scale that seems to happen on the item)

Howerver, the [MSPointerEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh466130.aspx) has a pointerType property, that lets you differentiate between pen, mouse, and touch.